# PHP to transfer (SEND) file to another Server?

Tags: php, file, send, transfer, put

In PHP, i know only how to `get` the files.
But now i don't know how to do with followings:

- How can i `distribute/ send/ transfer` the files onto another owned Server?
- Just to send from the host server. NOT the way to get from the target server.

Please suggest if you know.

Comment: You should be able to use php ftp functions http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ftp.php or CURL http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php to achive this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use curl, it support POST http method (if you receive file from html form), and ftp methods (if you had setup ftp server).

Answer (score 1):

If the other servers is yours, you can install a FTP server and use the ftp functions:

http://es2.php.net/ftp

http://es2.php.net/manual/es/function.ftp-fput.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `curl_XXX` functions for this.

Comment: Oh, is `curl` also for `sending`? What i've known before is just about `getting`.

Comment: It can do both. You can use CURLOPT_POST to submit form data. It can also do FTP file transfers in both directions.

Answer (score 0):

How will you recieve the file?

If you have a webserver listening for POST requests, I would recommend [cURL](http://php.net/curl).
If you're running some other sort of server I would recommend sending it via [sockets](http://php.net/fsockopen).

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can either install an FTP server on the servers you want to send the data to and then use [PHP's FTP functions](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) or use curl, and have a script running on the server you want to send the data to to pick up POST data coming in from the server you're sending the data from.

Answer (score 0):

1. Hey use php ftp function to transfer files on to the another server.
   But make sure that, server given you write permission to edit.
2. You can go through ftp_fput() method of php to transfer files on
   remote server. Go through php manual you will get ready examples for
   sending files.
3. Firstly use ftp_connect() function to connect to remote server.
   Then read files from your local directory using file functions and then use fput to put              file on to the remote server.